# @DecimalMin does not validate whether input is numeric, results in InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, json, spring, api

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html), `@DecimalMin` should check *both* whether the input is a number and if it is greater than the provided value, correct? Here is the definition:

> The annotated element must be a number whose value must be higher or
>   equal to the specified minimum.

I have a POJO, where I am trying to use the validation:

```
public class ConversionInputDto {

    @DecimalMin(value = "0.0", message = ERROR_INVALID_AMOUNT)
    private BigDecimal sourceAmount;

    // other variables, no-args constructor, getters

}
```

My controller has the `@Validated` annotation and the actual method looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/convert")
public ConversionInputDto convertTo(@RequestBody @Valid ConversionInputDto conversionInputDto) {
    // ...
}
```

However, when I send a String payload like: `"sourceAmount": "test"`, I get the following error:

```
"Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.math.BigDecimal` from String \"test\": not a valid representation; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException:
```

Should `@DecimalMin` not also ensure that the input is numeric, or have I missed something?

Comment: I think `BigDecimal sourceAmount = new BigDecimal("test")` won't ever make it "to validation"! (due to prior NumberFormatException ..on "desirialization level")

Comment: ..you could have more "luck" with `@DecimalMin(...)private String sourceAmount;` (?)

Comment: You are right, it works with String! But I am not sure if it is good practice, because I then become dependent on this validation, and also keeping currency as String does not allow for possible calculations / generally decreases flexibility. Then I guess I will add extra regexp pattern to check for numeric input.

Comment: ...Or I could add logic in getter to return BigDecimal, as the private String field will be encapsulated. Thanks a lot for your tip!

Comment: ..actually `number = "test"` is "blunder", but if you are really concerned about the type&message of exception, then this is a possible workaround (?) ..(but i would leave it `BigDecimal`, and "be happy with any exception":)

Comment: Yes, I think too I will leave it like this. I guess API users should know better what type of input to submit. Thanks a lot xerx593!